# How do i check broken links and images in my website?

Tags: dead-links

I have recently moved my website from one server to another server. for my confirmation i would like to check the dead links and the missing images on my website.

I would like to crawl every pages on the website and find the missing images and non working dead links.

Comment: See also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/209/good-tool-to-crawl-my-site-and-help-me-find-dead-link-and-unlinked-files and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/what-tools-to-use-for-automated-link-and-spellchecking

Answer (score 3):

I use a piece of software called [Xenu Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html).

I first used it about 10 years ago and the interface hasn't changed much in that time, but it works great for small to medium size websites.

It will still work on large websites, but it will take an age to crawl tens of thousands of dynamically generated content pages.

Comment: +1 because I can say that Xenu works better than any other I know to do this. However, for images, I just have a cronjob which checks my Apache logs - if it finds a broken image, I'll know about it that way.

Comment: One key thing to note with crawling tools is be sure you have not got any destructive links. E.g. Links to delete accounts, contacts, files etc. I've seen things go horribly wrong when these kind of tools rapidly erase all your content.  Using the web logs is a great way to catch the "low hanging fruit" that users are actually encountering.

Comment: @scunliffe, but hopefully these are triggered by POSTs and are behind security. :D

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Broken Image Finder Add-On, which detects unavailable images by scanning the currently visited website and its embedded stylesheets:
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/broken-image-finder/