# Website image/link/url checker

Tags: hyperlink

Is there any sufficient software or tools to use to check website on below aspects

1. Images sizes

   - Sometimes some images were uploaded very big without knowing, this causes bandwidth and speed
2. Broken links

   - Bad for user experiences
3. Broken url

   - Bad for user as well

I know a software called "Link Validate" or something. Anything else?

Comment: you could use javascript and find out if the objects exist when you try to go to them...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12854/how-do-i-check-broken-links-and-images-in-my-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) will follow all the links on a website and tell you if any lead to a 404 or if any lead to redirects (because you could make the site a bit faster by linking to the redirect destination instead). This should cover all of your link verification needs.

As far as image size, I can't think of much other than using `wget` to download your photos pages and then using `du` to find out what the biggest files are.

Answer (score 1):

I use a piece of software called [Xenu Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) for checking broken links.

I first used it about 10 years ago and the interface hasn't changed much in that time, but it works great for small to medium size websites.

It will still work on large websites, but it will take an age to crawl tens of thousands of dynamically generated content pages.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the image size, you can use [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) which can analyse all sorts of things that slow a page down. It particularly spots images where the image is displayed at a smaller size than the original file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox and don't mind using add ons then there are a handful of useful add ons to help out.

**[Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)** is a very useful add on for trouble shooting alot of your issues.

**[LinkChecker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linkchecker/)** is a great add on for finding broken links.

Answer (score 0):

**Performance Tools**

- [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/)
- [GTMatrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)

**404's and URL's**

- [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink)

**Image Optimization**

- [Smushit](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)