# How to detect broken external links and site wide spell checking?

Tags: links, 404, dead-links, spelling

I'm looking for known methods to scan our site and alert us of spelling errors and broken links. Our goals are basically to have something consistently checking the entire site for spelling errors and link problems.

We've been just using [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) which works pretty well for spot link checking, but it doesn't do any spell checking and it isn't automated.

Question(s):

- What's a good method for checking site wide spelling issues?
- What's a good method of automatically detecting broken external links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A1WebsiteAnalyzer](http://www.microsystools.com/products/website-analyzer/) is easy to use. You can automate via Windows scheduled tasks.

I haven't used [InSpyder](http://www.inspyder.com/products/InSite/Default.aspx) but it's the same price and does the same thing.