# Link error checking tool for linux

Tags: web-crawlers, dead-links

I use Xenu Kubj Sleuth to find out 404s and server errors on websites, but I'm not enjoying it, is there a better free tool out there that can preferably run in bash in linux that does the same thing or more?

Comment: This answer http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/248/1643 recommends linklint

Comment: What is it you don't like?

Answer (score -1):

[Link Examiner](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/lnkexam/freeware.htm) is a really good freeware to do this (and it add some bonus seo feature)